# Can read process memory, but fail to write the same memory contents

Tags: c++, windows, process, virtualbox

I am enumerating all memory blocks with MEM_COMMIT in a process, and try to write the same contents right after I read the memory block. So most of memory blocks have a Protect of 4, which is PAGE_READWRITE. I noticed that there are so many memory blocks that can be read but **can't be written**. Typical output looks like this :

```
  Reading : 0x012C0000 - Size : 10000 - Protect : 4
The same contents written successfully!!!
  Reading : 0x012D0000 - Size : 10000 - Protect : 4
The same contents written successfully!!!
  Reading : 0x012E0000 - Size : 10000 - Protect : 4
The same contents written successfully!!!
  Reading : 0x012F0000 - Size : 2000 - Protect : 4
The same contents written successfully!!!
```

However, most of other memory blocks can be read but cannot be written.

```
  Reading : 0x31340000 - Size : 200000 - Protect : 4
Failed to write the same memory contents.
  Reading : 0x31540000 - Size : 200000 - Protect : 4
Failed to write the same memory contents.
  Reading : 0x31740000 - Size : 200000 - Protect : 4
Failed to write the same memory contents.
  Reading : 0x31940000 - Size : 200000 - Protect : 4
Failed to write the same memory contents.
```

Any reason for this? Right now I cannot alter the memory I want to modify. I am using Windows XP 32 bit and I have my process privilege enabled and used this flag to open process :

```
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION
```

The target process is a VirtualBox process that I use for testing.

**Edit:** I used GetLastError() and the error returned is **"Attempt to access invalid address"**.

Comment: If you cannot help, please help other questions instead of downvoting my post.

Comment: "Attempt to access invalid address" - are this not say for self ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so that we can be sure it isn't just a bug in your code.  It would also be useful if anyone wants to attempt to reproduce the problem.